# MySQL get entry after certain element in an ordering

Tags: mysql, sorting

I have a `posts` table, where the `id`s are not necessarily in sequence. The posts should be sorted by their `created` timestamp value, but it is possible, that two posts have the same `created` timestamp, in which case I would like to sort them by their `id`.

Given this ordering, I was trying to find the entry that immediately precedes a specified entry.

Example: (descending order)

```
 id   | created
------|------------ 
 4    | 2017-01-05
 15   | 2017-01-04
 12   | 2017-01-04
 2    | 2017-01-04
 8    | 2017-01-02
 11   | 2017-01-01
```

(I simplified the timestamp to only the date, but you get the idea.)

In this example, given the `id` 2, I would like to return the `id` 8. After some experimentation I have come up with the following:

```
SELECT id 
FROM posts 
WHERE created < ? OR id < ? 
  AND created = ? 
ORDER BY created DESC, id DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

This works, given the timestamp and id in the correct places in the query, but is very tedious.

**My question is now:**

Is there, given an ordering, an easier way to find the preceding element?

**Clarification:**

The above code does return the correct results, but I was wondering whether there was some more general way to achieve the same, one that will be more easily adapted if the sorting specification changes..

Comment: It's a nonsense to suggest that the ids are out of sequence. Rows in an RDBMS table have no sequence other than that suggested by an ORDER BY clause.

Comment: That said, this is a surprisingly complex problem!!

Comment: If 1 and 9 both  fell on 2017-01-02, which one would you pick?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use tuples:

```
SELECT id 
FROM posts 
WHERE (created, id) < (?,?)
ORDER BY created DESC, id DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: nice didn't knkow about tuples

Comment: Note though how tuples respond to indexes :-(

Comment: And really I think the correct solution should require only '2' as input, right?

Comment: @Strawberry, MySQL will not use an index in this case (even though it's logically possible and PostgreSQL can do that), but the original query doesn't use an index too. And yes -  `created ` can be equal as required, but only if `id` is smaller (look at the original condition).

Comment: @Strawberry if i only have the `id` i would need a join. Want me to write that query too, even though it's not required in the question?

Comment: Well, actually you only need a subquery - so yeah, this answer's pretty smart. But, to my mind, an answer that uses indexes wins it ;-)

Comment: @Strawberry i could add a redundant condition `created < ?`. But this way i would filter "only" half of the table (in average). The only faster way i can think of is a UNION ALL optimization. But OP asked for "an easier way" :-)

Comment: Ooooh MySQL has tuples, this makes my life a whole lot easier :) Thank you so much!

Answer (score -1):

what you have is fine ... otherwise the only way i can think of is create an order out of that using concat and lpad but that's even more confusing to read than what you have.
the more confusing method using concat and lpad

```
SELECT id,created FROM POSTS
WHERE CONCAT(created,LPAD(id, 8, '0')) < CONCAT('2017-01-04',LPAD(2, 8, '0'))
ORDER BY created desc, id desc
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. The id is not guaranteed to be lower on earlier posts, but the post I'm looking for is guaranteed to have been created earlier or at the same time as the input post. (see example in question statement)

Comment: Well my code does produce the required results, but I was wondering if there is a more elegant solution that is more easily adaptable to a new ordering specification

Comment: i just updated my answer to create order out of your specs, but your method is probably faster as it doesn't have to concat and lpad,